# Install R Package XML in Debian / Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am just getting started with Ubuntu and want to program in R.  I successfully installed the latest version of R (currently 2.12.2) from the terminal.  I then attempted to run the following command:

```
> install.packages("XML")
Installing package(s) into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("XML") :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Would you like to create a personal library
'~/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.12'
to install packages into?  (y/n)
```

Should I create the personal directory or did I miss a step somewhere that allows me to write to the site library.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you start the `R` shell via `sudo` or just as a normal user? Normal users won't have permission to write into `/usr/local/lib/`, so if you start `R` with `sudo` first, it should allow writing into the site library directory.

Comment: Using `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/` is preferable. Unix is, after all, a multi-user system.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The comment by `sarnold` is quite correct.  In the Debian (and hence Ubuntu) package, the directory `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/` is created by the file `/var/lib/dpkg/info/r-base-core.postinst` script -- and the relevant code is:

```
# edd 03 Apr 2003  cf Section 10.1.2 of Debian Policy
if [ ! -e /usr/local/lib/R ]; then
  if mkdir /usr/local/lib/R 2>/dev/null; then
    chown root:staff /usr/local/lib/R
    chmod 2775 /usr/local/lib/R
  fi
fi
if [ ! -e /usr/local/lib/R/site-library ]; then
  if mkdir /usr/local/lib/R/site-library 2>/dev/null; then
    chown root:staff /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
    chmod 2775 /usr/local/lib/R/site-library
  fi
fi
```

so the directory is owned by `root:staff` and of mode 2775, or 'user and group read-write, others read-only'.

So to write there, you have two basic choices:

1. Always use `sudo` or become `root` which is clumsy.
2. Add yourself to the group `staff`.  There is probably a user-friendly GUI for it; I am Unix old-school and do that by hand by editing `/etc/group` and `/etc/gshadow` -- after that you can install directly (well you need a fresh shell to have those rights, or just start a new terminal). You can of course also pick a different group, or create one, but then you need to also alter the directory tree in `/usr/local/lib/R/` accordingly.

Hope this helps. The r-sig-debian list is a friendly place for Debian/Ubuntu questions like this and I recommend it. The question has come up there before.

**Edit:**  Also, a fair number of (more complicated) packages are part of Ubuntu / Debian, so to get XML you can just to `sudo apt-get install r-cran-xml`.  Do an `apt-cache search r-cran` to see what is available.

Comment: "sudo adduser USER GROUP" will add existing USER to existing GROUP.

Comment: Option 2. does not function on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It does; you just need to log out and log in again.

Answer (score 8):

The simplest option is to add yourself to the `staff` user group. Just run:

```
sudo adduser <user> staff
```

Replace `<user>` with your username.

Tested in Ubuntu 14.04