# problems installing packages on server after update to 2.15

Tags: r

I have a recurring problem installing packages, that often looks like this:

```
> install.packages("Biobase")
Installing package(s) into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("Biobase") :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Would you like to create a personal library
~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15
to install packages into?  (y/n) y
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
Loading Tcl/Tk interface ... done
Warning message:
package ‘Biobase’ is not available (for R version 2.15.0)
```

My `Sys.info()` is as follows:

```
> Sys.info()
                                     sysname 
                                     "Linux" 
                                     release 
                          "2.6.32-40-server" 
                                     version 
"#87-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 6 02:10:02 UTC 2012" 
                                    nodename 
                                    "******" 
                                     machine 
                                    "x86_64" 
                                       login 
                                        "**" 
                                        user 
                                        "**" 
                              effective_user 
                                        "**"
```

Is the error `package ‘Biobase’ is not available (for R version 2.15.0)` due to the fact that I have to install it in a personal library (apparently on the server I work on, the usual library is not writable)? How can I get around this, as I seem to get the same "not available for 2.15" error anytime I try to install a package.

Answer (score 4):

The `Biobase` package is available on Bioconductor, not through CRAN.
This is how you install it:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Biobase")
```

See [Bioconductor](http://www.Bioconductor.org) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding the following solution for anyone else that might stumble across this older post.

The root cause of the problem is ownership/permissions for the directory where R is installing the libraries.  To quote from a related post:

> "the directory is owned by root:staff and of mode 2775, or 'user and group read-write, others read-only'." (Dirk Eddelbuettel)

For more details and how to correct this, please refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560139/install-r-package-xml-in-debian-ubuntu).